# Music Sheet - Same note twice on same place

Tags: sheet-music

I have seen below highlighted note on one sheetmusic. I am wondering what does it mean. How to play this note in Piano. Why do they mention two tails for same note. if it is same note , there is only one note is required. Please explain the meaning of this note.

[image]

Comment: I don't know too much about piano sheets specifically but you can see this pattern often when there are two separate voices on the same staff. It means that both the lower and the higher voice play the same note. The two tails indicate that and make it easier to read each voice separately.

Comment: There have been several questions asking exactly this, and several with very similar thoughts. It is a dupe.

Comment: They are very common in classical guitar, where a fretted note is doubled with an open string.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen notes like that before so I searched it and find out what it supossed to mean.

Officially there are names for each part of a note:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stem_(music)

This specific, (in this case) doubled part is the stem.

I find some sites describing this note type, but first here is an answer directly from here:

[Why does this note have a stem pointing up and another pointing down?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/why-does-this-note-have-a-stem-pointing-up-and-another-pointing-down)

Not stack:

https://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/experts/robert/stemmed-notes/

> Sometimes you'll even have double stems with two different rhythms.
>   You'll have a half note and a quarter note on the same note. The note
>   holds for one line and the next line is going on with faster notes
>   while that note is continuing to hold. There's great complexity and
>   counter point delineating distinct musical lines. To be able to play
>   more than one on one instrument, like you do on the piano, on stringed
>   instruments like violin and cello, and guitar, classical guitar, we
>   all see these on a regular basis.

I'm glad I find you question because this was really interesting for me as well. I hope I helped :)

Comment: They are very common in classical guitar, where a fretted note is doubled with an open string.